# Yii2 encrypt and Mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption, yii2

I hope someone can help me with this.

I am saving a personal data into MYSQL by encrypting using Yii2 encrypt/decrypt function, testing without saving the content into the DB works.

However saving the content into the DB and retrieving it back, seems something goes wrong because I am not able to decrypt it.

My MYSQL scheme is this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customerHash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerUpdated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customerEmail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerPassword` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerToken` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerAddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerPhone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerPostcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerName` blob,
  `customerSurname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Yii code
  Encrypt

```
        $request=Yii::$app->request;
        $hash=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
        $model->customerHash=$hash;
        $model->customerName=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->encryptByKey($request->post('customerName'), $hash);
```

Decrypt

```
<? echo"Decode : ".Yii::$app->getSecurity()->decryptByKey($model->customerName, $model->customerHash);?>
```

Any help welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you tested that encrypted data is the same before before saving to database and after fetching from database?

Comment: Hi, There is no error , just show as empty.